# Trying to test a http service via Jasmin throws error: "Expected object to be a kind of AddUserShareModel, but was SafeSubscriber"

Tags: angular, typescript, http, testing, frontend

Im very new to frontend testing in Angular and typescript with Jasmin and trying to get into it by starting on smaller services in my current project. For this I chose a service that does nothing but send http requests and return the created/edited usershares(A usershare is a one-sided sharing of documents with another user of the program, an AddUserShareModel is the model sent to the backend to create a new usershare). I'm running into problems due to the asynchronous nature of these requests, specifically that my service returns an Observable of the model used to create the usershare which I can't extract the actual usershare and its properties from and get the Error displayed in the title: "Expected object to be a kind of AddUserShareModel, but was SafeSubscriber".

I tried to extract the object from the Observable by subscribing to it, but this doesnt seem to work here. Consulting the official documentation and searching online for a solution gave me multiple ways to fix similar - but not equal - problems that I can't apply here by myself, probably due to my current skill-level. The problem shouldn't be the implementation of the service itself since it works just fine when using the program.

The service I want to test:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AddUserShareModel } from '../shared/models/add.userShare.model';
import { ActiveRecipientModel } from '../shared/models/active-recipient-model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserShareService{
  private rootUrl = environment.rootUrl + "/api/UserShare";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  addUserShare(model: AddUserShareModel): Observable<AddUserShareModel> {
    return this.http.put<AddUserShareModel>(this.rootUrl + "/Add", model);
  }

  copyUserShare(model: AddUserShareModel): Observable<AddUserShareModel> {
    return this.http.put<AddUserShareModel>(this.rootUrl + "/copy", model);
  }

  updateIsActiveUserShare(model: ActiveRecipientModel): Observable<void> {
    return this.http.put<void>(this.rootUrl + "/updateIsActive", model);
  }

  getReceiverEmailProposal(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.http.get<string[]>(this.rootUrl + "/Proposal");
  }
}
```

My spec.ts test:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ActiveRecipientModel } from 'src/app/shared/models/active-recipient-model';
import { AddUserShareModel } from 'src/app/shared/models/add.userShare.model';
import { UserShareService } from '../../app/services/userShare.service';

describe('UserShareService', () => {
    let service: UserShareService;
    let httpClient: HttpClient;

    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
        providers: [UserShareService],
      });
      httpClient = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
      //service = TestBed.inject(UserShareService);
      service = new UserShareService(httpClient);

    });

    //these two expects are successfull

    it('should be created', () => {
      expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("should have defined method addUserShare", () => {
      expect(service.addUserShare).toBeDefined();
    });

    //this is where the error is thrown
    it('should add share', async() => {
      var model = new AddUserShareModel(20, "reciever@email.de", ["guid1", "guid2"]);
      var result: any = await service.addUserShare(model).subscribe(
        res => {
          return res;
        }

      );

      console.log(result);
      expect(await result).toBeTruthy();
      expect(await result).toBeDefined();
      expect(await result).toEqual(model);
      console.log("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", result);

    });

});
```

the AddUserShareModel:

```
export class AddUserShareModel {
    constructor(
       public daysActive: number,
       public receiverEmail: string,
       public documentIds: string[],
      ) {  }
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/testing-services#testing-http-services

Comment: https://braydoncoyer.dev/blog/how-to-unit-test-an-http-service-in-angular